# Sending Mail via SMTP in C# using BCC without TO

Tags: c#, email, smtp, bcc

I am trying to use the `System.Net.Mail.MailMessage` class in C# to create an email that is sent to a list of email addresses all via `BCC`. I do not want to include a `TO` address, but it seems that I must because I get an exception if I use an empty string for the `TO` address in the `MailMessage` constructor. The error states:

```
ArgumentException
The parameter 'addresses' cannot be an empty string.
Parameter name: addresses
```

Surely it is possible to send an email using only `BCC` as this is not a limitation of SMTP.

**Is there a way around this?**

Comment: I'd complain to MS about this.  It doesn't help you in the current situation though.

Comment: Complaining always helps. It gives a warm feeling of hate.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think if you comment out the whole `emailMessage.To.Add(sendTo);` line , it will send the email with `To` field empty.

Answer (score 12):

Do the same thing you do for internal mail blasts where you don't want people to reply-to-all all the time.

Send it **to** yourself (or a dummy account), then add your BCC list.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't even need to be a real e-mail address, I typically use `Mailer@CompanyName.com` for `TO`, and `NoReply@CompanyName` for `FROM`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to include a TO address. Just send it to a "junk" email address that you don't mind getting mail on.

Comment: I don't think you have to include a To-address.

Answer (score 1):

Just don't call the Add-method on the To-property.

Answer (score 0):

Must have a to address. It has been this way since the original sendmail an implementations in the 80s and all SMTP mailers, I know of, have the same requirement. You can just use a dummy address for to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a temporary fake address then remove it just after:

```
MailMessage msg = new MailMessage(from, "fake@example.com");
msg.To.Clear();
foreach (string email in bcc.Split(';').Select(x => x.Trim()).Where(x => x != ""))
{
     msg.Bcc.Add(email);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you were trying to do something like :

```
var msg = new MailMessage("no-reply@notreal.com", "");
```

That's why you were seeing the error message.

Instead, try something like this:

```
MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.notreal.com");
msg.From = new MailAddress("no-reply@notreal.com");
//msg.To.Add("target@notreal.com"); <--not needed
msg.Bcc.Add("BCCtarget@notreal.com");
```